# Azure Service Bus performance issue MassTransit

Tags: azure, amqp, masstransit, servicebus

So I've been playing around with MassTransit and Azure Service Bus Premium, here's a sample of one of my consumers. Hypothetical initial load for one publisher would be about 1000 messages a second. However whenever I attempt to configure a consumer, it seems to generally average out at about 20-40 messages per loop.

```
cfg.ReceiveEndpoint("ReceivePoint", e =>{
    e.PrefetchCount = 500;
    e.MaxConcurrentCalls = 20;
    e.Batch<IBlahContract>(b => {
       b.MessageLimit = 500;
       b.TimeLimit = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(1);
       b.Consumer(() => new BatchBlahConsumer(provider.GetRequiredService<IRepository>(), provider.GetRequiredService<ILogger<BatchBlahConsumer>>()));
    });
});
```

I did try  [Throughput test](https://github.com/Azure-Samples/service-bus-dotnet-messaging-performance/tree/master/ThroughputTest) which managed a thousand plus messages a second. Did anyone get any tips on how to achieve optimal performance? And might it make more sense to consider a managed instance of RabbitMq since this needs to scale? It just feels like Azure Service Bus isn't really suited to such high throughput?

Edit: Slight addition to this, suspect it's related to a requirement to keep prefetch to about 20 and then consumer concurrency is what really defines performance. So basically, it needs consumer level configuration in terms of estimated requirements. Which would make me lean more towards using rabbit.

Answer (score 3):

Your batch message limit is 500, which is honestly way too high. With the MaxConcurrentCalls set at 20, you'll always hit the timeout instead of the batch size limit, because the Azure client library will only ever deliver 20 messages at once, and the batch size is significantly higher than that value (500 vs 20). You need to set it high enough that it can complete a batch or you'll always be completing the batch on timeout alone.

Lower the batch size, and increase the MaxConncurrentCalls, so that they are the same, or at least so the batch size is less than the concurrent calls limit, so that batches can be completed upon message receipt instead of waiting to time out.

Comment: That would make sense. Had actually since started playing with it with a higher concurrency and lower prefetch. It still seems to struggle with anything like a 1000msgs/s  so given our scale, not sure if one message unit would be sufficient.